# How to retrieve created Topics (and Queues) of session with ActiveMQ 5.x

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I created different topics using `session.createTopic(topicname)`. How can I retrieve a list of all available topics in the session? I tried to use `session.getStats()`, but I can't iterate over it, to get the information I need.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? Are you using ActiveMQ 5.x or some version of ActiveMQ Artemis?

Comment: I have both and I jumped in between. But now i turn back to ActiveMQ 5.x. I do not fully understand the difference between them yet.

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis is the next generation message broker from ActiveMQ. It will become ActiveMQ 6.0 when feature parity is satisfactory to the community. It already supports most of the features of ActiveMQ 5.x plus many more that 5.x doesn't have. Performance and scalability are also *much* improved over 5.x. If you're starting a new project I would recommend using ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answers are so clarifying! So should I already prefer ActiveMQ Artemis over 5.x ?

Comment: If you have an existing investment ActiveMQ 5.x infrastructure that you're trying to work with then stick with that for now and start investigating how to migrate. However, if you're starting a new project then I would highly recommend using ActiveMQ Artemis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following command you will get the all the topics from the broker:

```
 Set<ActiveMQTopic> topics = activeMqConnection.getDestinationSource().getTopics();
```

But I don't think if it's want you want. Another option would be:

```
session.getSessionStats()
.getProducers()
.stream()
.map(JMSProducerStatsImpl::getDestination)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The JMS API doesn't provide any method which provides a list of all destinations created with a `javax.jms.Session`.

I recommend you store the `javax.jms.Destination` instances you create in a local data structure (e.g. a `java.util.ArrayList`) in order to keep track of them.

Keep in mind that both `javax.jms.Session.createTopic(String)` and `javax.jms.Session.createQueue(String)` just create a client-side instance of a `javax.jms.Topic` or `javax.jms.Queue` respectively. They *do not* actually create a topic or queue on the broker. This is noted in the JavaDoc, e.g.:

> Note that this method simply creates an object that encapsulates the name of a topic. It does not create the physical topic in the JMS provider. JMS does not provide a method to create the physical topic, since this would be specific to a given JMS provider. Creating a physical topic is provider-specific and is typically an administrative task performed by an administrator, though some providers may create them automatically when needed. The one exception to this is the creation of a temporary topic, which is done using the createTemporaryTopic method.

The `getStats()` method you cited is not part of the JMS API. It is unique to the ActiveMQ 5.x JMS client implementation. Furthermore, it does not track the names of destinations created with the corresponding session.